# Given N arrays of integers of N elements, check if X can be formed by taking one element from each array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given N arrays of N elements, and a number X, check if X can be formed by taking an element from each array.

You have to take 1 and only 1 element from each array.

For N = 2, we need to find a pair which can be done in O(n) time (using a set or assuming that the array was sorted).
For N = 3, the complexity will be O(n2)?

For N = 4, it can be done n2Log(n) time.

How to generalized for N arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some variant of [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and can be solved similarly using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in [pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) time:

```
D[0][0] = true
D[0][w] = false   | w != 0
D[i][w] = OR { D[i-1][w-x] | for each x in array i }
```

Then, you are looking for the value of `D[n][X]`.

Intuitively, what you are doing is checking for each element in the `i`th array, and checks where its leading you to for each `w <= X`, and then checking recursively if this can be achieved. Note that the recursion here is symbolic, as dynamic programming doesn't require recursive solution.

Time complexity of the solution is `O(n^2 * X)`, since each entry of the table takes `O(n)` time to calculate, and there are `n*X` entries in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of beginner in the world of algorithms but here is an attempt by me to solve the above mentioned problem.

So the time complexity of my algorithm is somewhere ~ O(n*n*l*logn). Now here n is the number of arrays and l is the length of each array, so the example which I have considered while solving this problem has n = 4 and l = 3.

Please let me know if I make any mistakes and I will improve my answer accordingly.

So my algorithm is something like this:-

```
1. I store all the array values in n*l 2-D array where each row represents an array and l is the column number of each array.
2. I keep a global set of integers in which while I iterate over i arrays, I store the sum of all the possible values.
```

The example which I have considered for this code is given as below

```
4 3 26
1 4 5
2 3 6
7 1 3
8 4 2
```

Input Structure:-

```
1. First line contains three integers n,l,sum where n is the number of arrays, l is the length of each array and sum is the required sum that we need to check, whether it's possible to achieve or not.
2. Next n lines, each line containing l values are the elements for the ith array.
```

Now below is my code, written in c++. I think it's pretty straightforward to understand.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n,l,sum;
  cin>>n>>l;
  cin>>sum;
  vector<vector<int> > A(n, vector<int>(l));
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<l; j++) {
      cin>>A[i][j];
    }
  }
  vector<vector<int> > dp(1000,vector<int>(1000,0));
  dp[0][0] = 1;
  set<int> sum_intervals;
  // initially for filling up dp array with values of first row
  for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
    dp[0][A[0][i]] = 1;
    sum_intervals.insert(A[0][i]);
  }

  for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<l; j++) {
      set<int> temp = sum_intervals;
      for(set<int>::iterator it=sum_intervals.begin(); it!=sum_intervals.end(); it++) {
        dp[i][*it+A[i][j]] = 1;
        temp.insert(*it+A[i][j]);
      }
      sum_intervals = temp;
    }
  }
  if(A[n-1][sum]) {
    cout<<"Yayy answer exists"<<endl;
  } else {
    cout<<"Sorry, no answer exists"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!